# Javascript not work in require php file on Class "content" AdminLTE

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, adminlte

I have 2 page **chemical_data.php** and **chemical_selectAll.php**. I will test `alert()` on click button but button `id = "test1"` not show `alert('1')`

**chemical_data.php**

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready( function() {

             $('#OutputALLResult').load('chemical_selectAll.php');
             $('#test').click(function(){
                alert('1');  
             });
        }); 
    </script>
    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">
    <div class="col-md-12">
         <div id="OutputResult"></div>
    </div>
    <hr>
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="test">testClick</button>
        <div id="OutputALLResult">Empty Data</div>

    </section>
```

**chemical_selectAll.php**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready( function() {
            $('#test1').click(function(){
            alert('1');  
            });
    });    
</script>
<button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="test1">test1</button>
```

Comment: @jeff Sorry. it's wrong code. I edited.

Comment: I'm not sure that's why i'm not submitting an answer. I suspect the second document ready is not fired

Comment: Yes, I got it. My Page has Error other section.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I not changed any code. But in my local server this works well. You  can check what error occurred

Comment: Yes, I got it. My Page has Error other section.Thanks a lot.